# Change data-type String

Tags: esp8266, string, ir, data-type

I'm currently working with an ESP8266 NodeMCU V3 and an IR transmitter breakout board. The module receives NEC IR commands trough a HTTP request and then sends them trough the IR transmitter. Getting the command from the HTTP request and sending static (pre-programmed) IR NEC commands works perfectly. The problem however is that the NEC IR command I receive trough HTTP is in a `String` variable/data type (after processing). `irsend.sendNEC();` however requires `uint64_t` as the input type, according to the error message I get in the Arduino IDE.

I don't really know my way around C data types to be honest. Searches like "Arduino String to uint64_t" have came up empty or reversed. One [post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=123486.0) came close to what I'm trying to accomplish, but `irsend.sendNEC(strtoul(irrequest));` didn't do the trick either.

Arduino code;

- Check for `// Send IR NEC command` almost at the bottom
- The second and third `irsend.sendNEC();` are an example and not in the final code
- HTTP request is formatted like http://192.168.1.xxx/rest/ir/nec/0xFB0042BD

`Sketch.ino`

```cpp
// Configuration
const char* CONFIG_SSID      = "mywifi";
const char* CONFIG_PSK       = "wifipassword";
const int   CONFIG_SERIAL    = 115200;
const int   CONFIG_PORT      = 80;
const int   CONFIG_TIMEOUT   = 5000;
const int   CONFIG_IRTPIN    = 2;

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

// Include libraries
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <IRremoteESP8266.h>
#include <IRsend.h>
#include <IRrecv.h>
#include <IRutils.h>

// Create webserver object
WiFiServer server(CONFIG_PORT);

// Create IR Send object
IRsend irsend(CONFIG_IRTPIN);

// Setup instructions
void setup() {

  // Start serial and LED
  Serial.begin(CONFIG_SERIAL);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting setup");
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 1);

  // Start WiFi connection
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_SSID);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(CONFIG_SSID, CONFIG_PSK);

  // Wait for WiFi connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("WiFi connected!");

  // Print WiFi connection information
  Serial.print("  SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  Serial.print("  RSSI: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI());
  Serial.println(" dBm");
  Serial.print("  Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Start webserver
  Serial.println("Starting webserver...");
  server.begin();
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Webserver started!");

  // Print webserver information
  Serial.print("  Host: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("  Port: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_PORT);

  // Start IR Send
  Serial.println("Starting IR Send...");
  irsend.begin();
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("IR Send started!");

  // Setup complete
  Serial.println("Setup completed");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 0);
  Serial.println();

}

// Loop instructions
void loop() {

  // Wait for new client
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {

    // New client
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 1);
    Serial.println("New client connected");

    // Wait nicely for the client to complete its full request
    unsigned long timeout = millis() + CONFIG_TIMEOUT;
    Serial.println("Waiting for client request to finish...");
    while (!client.available() && millis() < timeout) {
      delay(1);
    }

    // End client connection when timeout is reached to not hold up availability
    if (millis() < timeout) {
      Serial.println("Client request finished!");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Client request timeout!");
      client.flush();
      client.stop();
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 0);
      Serial.println();
      return;
    }

    // Catch client request
    String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print("Request header: ");
    Serial.println(req);
    if (req.indexOf(F("/rest/ir/nec/")) != -1) {

      // Get IR Send NEC request
      String irrequest = req;
      irrequest.remove(0, ((irrequest.lastIndexOf("/rest/ir/nec/")) + 13));
      irrequest.remove((irrequest.indexOf(" ")));
      Serial.print("IR Send NEC code: ");
      Serial.println(irrequest);

      // Send IR NEC command
      Serial.println("Sending IR NEC command");
      irsend.sendNEC(irrequest);    // <<< here lays the problem
      irsend.sendNEC(0xFB0042BD);   // This works
      irsend.sendNEC("0xFB0042BD"); // This doesn't

      // Send HTTP response
      Serial.println("Sending HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
      client.println("OK");

    } else {

      // Invalid request
      Serial.println("Invalid client request");
      Serial.println("Sending HTTP/1.1 404 response");
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html><body>Not found</body></html>");

    }

    // Flush output buffer
    Serial.println("Flushing output buffer");
    client.flush();
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 0);
    Serial.println();
    return;

  }

}
```

Comment: `irsend.sendNEC(strtoul(irrequest.c_str(), NULL, 10)); ` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/ https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`irsend.sendNEC(strtoul(irrequest.c_str(), NULL, 10));` did the trick with the help of [Juraj](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/37622/juraj). Much thanks! I only had the set `10` to `16` to get it to work.

Working code:

```cpp
// Configuration
const char* CONFIG_SSID      = "mywifi";
const char* CONFIG_PSK       = "wifipassword";
const int   CONFIG_SERIAL    = 115200;
const int   CONFIG_PORT      = 80;
const int   CONFIG_TIMEOUT   = 5000;
const int   CONFIG_IRTPIN    = 2;

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

// Include libraries
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <IRremoteESP8266.h>
#include <IRsend.h>
#include <IRrecv.h>
#include <IRutils.h>

// Create webserver object
WiFiServer server(CONFIG_PORT);

// Create IR Send object
IRsend irsend(CONFIG_IRTPIN);

// Setup instructions
void setup() {

  // Start serial and LED
  Serial.begin(CONFIG_SERIAL);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting setup");
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 1);

  // Start WiFi connection
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_SSID);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(CONFIG_SSID, CONFIG_PSK);

  // Wait for WiFi connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("WiFi connected!");

  // Print WiFi connection information
  Serial.print("  SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  Serial.print("  RSSI: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI());
  Serial.println(" dBm");
  Serial.print("  Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Start webserver
  Serial.println("Starting webserver...");
  server.begin();
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Webserver started!");

  // Print webserver information
  Serial.print("  Host: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("  Port: ");
  Serial.println(CONFIG_PORT);

  // Start IR Send
  Serial.println("Starting IR Send...");
  irsend.begin();
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("IR Send started!");

  // Setup complete
  Serial.println("Setup completed");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 0);
  Serial.println();

}

// Loop instructions
void loop() {

  // Wait for new client
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {

    // New client
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 1);
    Serial.println("New client connected");

    // Wait nicely for the client to complete its full request
    unsigned long timeout = millis() + CONFIG_TIMEOUT;
    Serial.println("Waiting for client request to finish...");
    while (!client.available() && millis() < timeout) {
      delay(1);
    }

    // End client connection when timeout is reached to not hold up availability
    if (millis() < timeout) {
      Serial.println("Client request finished!");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Client request timeout!");
      client.flush();
      client.stop();
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 0);
      Serial.println();
      return;
    }

    // Catch client request
    String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print("Request header: ");
    Serial.println(req);
    if (req.indexOf(F("/rest/ir/nec/")) != -1) {

      // Get IR Send NEC request
      String irrequest = req;
      irrequest.remove(0, ((irrequest.lastIndexOf("/rest/ir/nec/")) + 13));
      irrequest.remove((irrequest.indexOf(" ")));
      Serial.print("IR Send NEC code: ");
      Serial.println(irrequest);

      // Send IR NEC command
      Serial.println("Sending IR NEC command");
      irsend.sendNEC(strtoul(irrequest.c_str(), NULL, 16));

      // Send HTTP response
      Serial.println("Sending HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
      client.println("OK");

    } else {

      // Invalid request
      Serial.println("Invalid client request");
      Serial.println("Sending HTTP/1.1 404 response");
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html><body>Not found</body></html>");

    }

    // Flush output buffer
    Serial.println("Flushing output buffer");
    client.flush();
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 0);
    Serial.println();
    return;

  }

}
```